# Creating scanner with multiple words

Tags: java

I need to include 10 variables but when I type in anything it comes up with only 1 of the variables I need to know how to make it so for example when "Gaming" is typed, the program comes back with "Do you like gaming?" right now it is at the point where anything I type it comes up with "Do you like uni?"

I have tried searching google for 3 hours and have done everything they have said and I can't find it. using .contains doesn't work for some reason.

```
    Scanner chatterbot = new Scanner(System.in);    
    String uni = ("University");
    String gaming = ("Gaming");

    uni = chatterbot.nextLine();
    if (uni.contains("University"))
        System.out.println("Do you like uni?");
    uni = chatterbot.nextLine();
    if (uni.contains("Yes"))
        System.out.println("Do you study one of SE CS or IT?");
    else if (uni.contains("No"))
        System.out.println("Do you study one of SE CS or IT?");
    uni = chatterbot.nextLine();
    if (uni.contains("Yes"))
        System.out.println("That is really great!");
    else if (uni.contains("No"))
        System.out.println("That is not good!");
    System.exit(0);


    gaming = chatterbot.nextLine();
    if (gaming.contains("Gaming"))
        System.out.println("Do you like gaming?");
    gaming = chatterbot.nextLine();
    if (gaming.contains("Yes"))
        System.out.println("What kind of games do you like to play?");
```

I expect the output to be if the user types Uni then it says "Do you like uni?" and when you type gaming it says "Do you like gaming?" The uni part works but when I type Gaming nothing appears.

Comment: Don't use `new String("University")`, just do `String uni = "University";`

Comment: Also remove the semicolon after the last `if`

Comment: No reason to use 2 different String fields for this. Just use `String input = chatterbot.nextLine();` first time and use `input = chatterbot.nextLine();` second time. No need to instantiate strings with University and Gaming values either.

Answer (score 1):

When you call chatterbot.nextLine() your input is consumed so if you call nextLine() again it waits for the next input.
But by saving the input in a variable you can compare it to more than one value.

This should work:

```
Scanner chatterbot = new Scanner(System.in);    
String input = chatterbot.nextLine();
if (input.contains("University")) {
   System.out.println("Do you like uni?");
} else if (input.contains("Gaming")) {
   System.out.println("Do you like gaming?");
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to add multiple answers for questions.